# How can I consume message from kafka in order?

Tags: mysql, go, apache-kafka, go-gorm, sarama

### Background

A producer produces some data and send to Kafka in order, like:

**{uuid: 123  status: 1}**

**{uuid: 123  status: 3}**

**status 1** *means begin*

**status 3** *means succeed*

I use **sarama.NewConsumerGroup(xx, xx, config).Consume(xx, xx, myhandler)** to consume with the code:

```golang
func (h myhandler) ConsumeClaim(sess sarama.ConsumerGroupSession, claim sarama.ConsumerGroupClaim) error {
    for msg := range claim.Messages() {

        key := fmt.Sprintf("%q-%d-%d", msg.Topic, msg.Partition, msg.Offset)
        _, err := rdb.RedisClient.Get(h.ctx, key).Result()
        if err == redis.Nil {
            msgQueue <- msg.Value
            sess.MarkMessage(msg, "")
            rdb.RedisClient.Set(h.ctx, key, none, 12*time.Hour)
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Errorln("RedisClient get key error : ", err)
            return err
        } else {
            continue
        }

    }
    return nil
}

msgQueue := make(chan interface{}, 1000)
```

And then I decode the value in msgQueue to a struct and insert a record into mysql.

### Question

Normally, final data **status is '3'**, but I find that sometimes **it is '1'**

And I find the message order in channel **msgQueue** is not fixed.

So how can I ensure the final status of data is **3** ?

### How to fix

**I have provided a method that is not good enough to see how it can be optimized.**

```
    conn := &gorm.DB{}
    data := &Log{}
    if data.Status != 1 {
        conn = conn.Clauses(clause.OnConflict{
            Columns:   []clause.Column{{Name: "uuid"}},
            DoUpdates: clause.AssignmentColumns([]string{"status"}),
        })
    }
    conn.Create(data)
    return conn.Error
```

And mysql has a unique constraint index for **uuid**.

When the data order is **{uuid: 123  status: 1}**,
**{uuid: 123  status: 3}**, It's right.

When the data order is **{uuid: 123  status: 3}**,
**{uuid: 123  status: 1}**, the final status is also right, but it will return error **Error 1062: Duplicate entry '123' for key 'unique_index_uuid'**.

It's not beautiful. So how can I optimize or are there other ways to do it?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the topic partitions. Kafka does not provide ordering guarantees within a topic, only within a partition.

In other words, if you sent a message A, then message B **to partition 0**, then the order will be that: first A, then B. But if they end up on different partitions it can happen that B is written to its partitions, before A is written to its.

Here's a quote from Confluent's web site:

> Kafka only provides a total order over records within a partition, not between different partitions in a topic. Per-partition ordering combined with the ability to partition data by key is sufficient for most applications. However, if you require a total order over records this can be achieved with a topic that has only one partition, though this will mean only one consumer process per consumer group.

[Link](https://docs.confluent.io/5.4.1/kafka/introduction.html#consumers)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know why the order is not fixed. But my real problem is how can I ensure the final status of data is 3 ? I have provided a method that is not good enough to see how it can be optimized.

Comment: I have added under my question.Please help!

Comment: So basically your question has nothing to do with Kafka, it has to do with your business logic. You need to think how to handle cases where a message status is skipped (e.g. what if you receive a message with status 3, and status 1 was never sent).

Answer (score -1):

i think you can produce the two message as you provide

**{uuid: 123 status: 1}**

**{uuid: 123 status: 3}**

with the same sarama.ProducerMessage Key in order. then the two messages will be in the same partition you can consume them in order.